# When mirroring a whole root zone rpool, do you have to install a boot block?

Tags: boot, solaris, zfs, sparc

I am mirroring a zfs rpool for a whole root zone to move from one storage array to another. I have mirrored the disk, but do I need to install a boot block on the new disk?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see [How to Create a Mirrored Root Pool (Post Installation)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gkdep/index.html).

> Apply boot blocks to the second disk after resilvering is complete.
>
> ```
> sparc# installboot -F zfs /usr/platform/`uname -i`/lib/fs/zfs/bootblk /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0
>
> x86# installgrub /boot/grub/stage1 /boot/grub/stage2 /dev/rdsk/c1t1d0s0
> ```
>
> Verify that you can boot successfully from the second disk.

Comment: Thanks. I knew you did for the Global OS, but wasn't sure on the zones.

Comment: zones don't get boot blocks as they share the kernel w/the global.
Though I have yet to play with kernel zones on v11.

Comment: It doesn't hurt to install it, but I believe that the boot block is now copied in a mirrored rpool -- at least on SPARC in later releases of v10, as well as in v11 of Solaris.

Comment: @user1712037 Sorry, I did not read about the zones in your question, so the answer was just about the normal system.

Comment: Please notice that you have to use installboot on global zone in Solaris 10. On Solaris 11.1 this is no longer necessary unless you are installing the boot disks in a different pool: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29007/gjtuk.html